# Scala: Matching tuples: unreachable code

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Task: Given one element get another one from 2-element tuple. Why this code fails:

```
 def neighbor(vertice:String, key:(String, String)):String = key match {
    case (vertice,x) => x
    case (x,vertice) => x //unreachable code??
  }
```

Running:

```
   println(neighbor("foo",("foo","bar")))
   println(neighbor("foo",("bar","foo")))
```

Returns:

```
bar
foo
```

How to make this work? Why second `case` is unreachable?

Comment: [this article explains this problem quite well](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-unreachable-code-due-to-variable-pattern-message)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def neighbor(vertice:String, key:(String, String)):String = key match {
  case (`vertice`,x) => x
  case (x,`vertice`) => x //unreachable code??
}
```

or use `Vertice` with an upper case V. Otherwise the pattern matching would think that you're just referring to any value. That's why in this case you get the unreachable code error. Here is an [ideOne](https://ideone.com/FB5Stp).

Comment: Thanks! Yet another Scala cryptic idiosyncrasy, very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you expect, but the code that you wrote most likely does not do what you think it does. I'm guessing that you think that the first `case` would match if the first element of the tuple is equal to the `vertice` variable that you pass to the method, and the second `case` would match if the second element of the tuple is equal to the `vertice` parameter.

If that's what you want, write it like this:

```
def neighbor(vertice:String, key:(String, String)):String = key match {
  case (left, x) if left == vertice => x
  case (x, right) if right == vertice => x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Smarter people than me will confirm / correct me, but I'm fairly sure that your two cases are strictly identical. Name declared in cases are new variables, and in your case they shadow your method parameters.

I believe your code to be strictly equivalent to:

```
def neighbor(vertice:String, key:(String, String)):String = key match {
  case (a,b) => b
  case (a,b) => a //unreachable code!!
}
```

Written that way, it makes much more sense for your second case not to be reachable, doesn't it?